# Images not being displayed in JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using the Netbeans IDE and when I use the "Clean and Build Project" to make an executable jar file of my program, it doesn't keep the images. I have the images located in "src/resources".

I am getting the images though code the following way:

```
setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png")));
```

How do I get the images to show up in the executable jar file?

Comment: almost duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596487/imageicons-on-jbutton-are-not-showing-up-in-runnable-jar-file

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias I've tried that they said in that post and none of it seems to work for me :\

Answer (score 0):

If your image is located in src/resources your line of code to set the image file should be like this

```
setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/icon.png")));
```

Comment: What are you trying to set an image to? A JLabel? I think it might help if you posted more of you're code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the path `/resources/icon.png`.  Remember, when you use `getClass().getResource` with a relative path, the path will be relative to the class's package, not it's root.